# T-SQL: if exists always return true?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, exists, if-statement

What do you think , does the Stored Procedure always return 1 ?

I am concerned about the if exists(..)

```
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @IsUserExisting bit

 SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF Exists
 (
  Select null FROM G_User WHERE
    SamAccountName = @SamAccountName
   AND NetBIOSDomainName = @NetBIOSDomainName   
 )
  BEGIN
     SET @IsUserExisting = 1     
  END
    ELSE
  BEGIN
     SET @IsUserExisting = 0    
  END

 Select @IsUserExisting

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if the WHERE clause doesn't return anything IF Exists() returns false and consequently @IsUserExisting is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Makis already answered your question, but i would like to suggest the following

You could simplify your code with:

```
declare @IsUserExisting bit;
set @IsUserExisting = (
select count(*) from G_User
where SamAccountName = @SamAccountName and
      NetBIOSDomainName = @NetBIOSDomainName);

select @IsUserExisting;
```

I think the following is even shorter in your case.

```
select count(*) from G_User
where SamAccountName = @SamAccountName and
NetBIOSDomainName = @NetBIOSDomainName)
```

Comment: That returns the amount of records it can find which meets your where clause.

Comment: so my code works I just have to replace select null with select count(*) ?

Comment: Your code already works like Makis stated, i would however go with my second example.

Comment: funny why the heck did my boss say the code will always return true... that just confused me so I asked here...

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE @IsUserExisting bit

 SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF Exists
 (
  Select null FROM G_User WHERE
    SamAccountName = @SamAccountName
   AND NetBIOSDomainName = @NetBIOSDomainName   
 )
  BEGIN
     SET @IsUserExisting = 1     
  END
    ELSE
  BEGIN
     SET @IsUserExisting = 0    
  END

 Select @IsUserExisting

END
```

i tried using this but when true it sets `@IsUserExisting = -1` !!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Select Count(*) if you are only testing to see if something exists.  While it should return fairly quickly in this case, If EXISTS() will return true immediately when it finds a matching record.  Select Count(*) will look at all records in order to give you a complete count, thus adding unnecessary overhead.